# How to create more than one reports in a crystal report c#?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a table which stores the salary slip records for an employee.

**tbl_Slip**
SlipNo*
EmpID
Month-Year
FacultyID
Additions

It is linked to another table that stores the employee's information.

**tbl_EmpInfo**
EmpID
EmpName
etc...

I want to generate salary slips for every employee in tbl_EmpInfo. I want to display one slip report at one page.(Do subreports allow this)
The fields that I want to display in the report are from both tables. 
I cannot think of an approach to do this task. If anyone can please explain me this. I am really struggling at this as I am new to crystal Reports.
Please also provide links that can help me.
I have http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-without-database.htm
one.

Your help would be really appreciated.

Comment: "More than one reports?" are you saying abt the more no of same reports, or different types of reports?

Comment: salary slip of EmpID 1 ; 
salary slip of EmpID 2 ;
and so on...  
But the salary slips must be on different pages.

Comment: just create a group on EmpID and design a report for a whole page ! 
and enter EmpID as parameter, so that for all EmpIDs you will be genereated salary slip in induvidual page.

Answer (score 0):

Create xsd with 2 datatables(EMP, EMPSalary) and add one-to-many relationship
Refer those tables on crystal report. I do not think you need sub report. 
Create group section based on EmpID and add the code which is ur reference link.
and restrict detail section per page